# Swift: in which method is push notifications counter cleared?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

My iOS app handles push notifications like the following:

```
func showNotificationDetails(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], application:UIApplication) {
    print("showNotificationDetails")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let notificationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DynamicEventsViewController") as! DynamicEventsViewController
    notificationController.isLoadedFromNotification = true
    notificationController.eventTitle = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"] as! String
    notificationController.eventDescription = userInfo["aps"]!["message"] as! String
    notificationController.isLoadedFromNotification = true

    if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController {
        tabBarController.presentViewController(notificationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let state:UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if (state == UIApplicationState.Inactive || state == UIApplicationState.Background) {
        self.showNotificationDetails(userInfo, application: application)
    }
    else if (state == UIApplicationState.Active) {
        let alertNewNotification = UIAlertController(title: "New notification received!", message: "Would you like to see details?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertNewNotification.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Show", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.showNotificationDetails(userInfo, application: application)
        }))
        alertNewNotification.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Later", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            alertNewNotification.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController {
            tabBarController.presentViewController(alertNewNotification, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Even if the user taps on `Later` then the notifications counter is set to 0 anyway and there is no notification banner anymore so that it is lost forever. Why?

Comment: so what is your question? where the counter is clear? or why banner don't come or anything else

Comment: Sorry, I'm making a lot of confusion today with push notifications because it is the first time I've tried to implement them. I guess I have just resolved the counter issue but I still would like to know how to get a banner even if the app is active...maybe by using a 3rd part framework?

Answer (score 1):

notification banner only show when app is not active

so you should handle this notification by yourself

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking too but in which way? Shall I use a 3-rd part framework? I would not know where to start from...can you link me anything?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this [TWMessageBarManager](https://github.com/terryworona/TWMessageBarManager)

When you are showing the alert from the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method at the same time you can call this library's message to show the notification banner

Your sample code for display can be like this:

```
TWMessageBarManager.sharedInstance().showMessageWithTitle("Title", description: "Description", type: TWMessageBarMessageType.Info)
```

If you want to display the data of `showNotificationDetails` you can call it inside that method also